# Why does the Additive rule work as it does?

Tags: probability

For non-mutually exclusive events, if there are probabilities for event A and event B, then I'm learning the additive theorem written as:

$P(A or B) = P(A)+ P(B) − P(AB)$

Why do we subtract P(AB)? The references I've read are terse. I gather it's because P(A) + P(B) accounts for P(AB) twice, but that doesn't make sense to me. Can anybody explain it?

Comment: Have you seen the Venn diagram explaining it ?

Comment: One way to think of it is that $A \cup B = A \cup E$, where $E = B - A \cap B$. The event $E$ contains all outcomes in $B$ that do not also belong to $A$. Notice that the events $A$ and $E$ are disjoint. So, $P(A \cup B) = P(A \cup E) = P(A) + P(E) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, I went over a few of those (one from varsitytutors.com, etc.) and they make a certain amount of sense visually but don't really help me with the reasoning.

Comment: The way @littleO expands the terms does a lot to explain the Venn diagram coloring. Thanks! This helps.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|A\cup B| = |A|+ |B|- |A\cap B|$ since the elements $x\in A\cap B$ are counted twice, in $|A|$ and in $|B|$, and so they need to be subtracted once in $|A\cap B|$.